# How can I implement a vectorizer implementation of the indice tracking of the following Decision Tree Code?

Tags: python, numpy, split, vectorization, decision-tree

**I had the following exercise:**

Next, you'll write a helper function called split_dataset that takes in the data at a node and a feature to split on and splits it into left and right branches. Later in the lab, you'll implement code to calculate how good the split is.

The function takes in the training data, the list of indices of data points at that node, along with the feature to split on.
It splits the data and returns the subset of indices at the left and the right branch.
For example, say we're starting at the root node (so node_indices = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]), and we chose to split on feature 0, which is whether or not the example has a brown cap.
The output of the function is then, left_indices = [0,1,2,3,4,7,9] (data points with brown cap) and right_indices = [5,6,8] (data points without a brown cap)

**Here is my implementation**

```
def split_dataset(X, node_indices, feature):
    left_indices = []
    right_indices = []
    
    for idx in node_indices:
        if X[idx, feature] == 1:
            left_indices.append(idx)
        else:
            right_indices.append(idx)        
    return left_indices, right_indices
```

**Is there any more efficient and vectorized way to implement this without a for loop using numpy?**

Answer (score 1):

**I've managed to make this work:**

```
def split_dataset(X, node_indices, feature):
    indices = np.array(node_indices)
    left_indices = indices[np.argwhere(X[node_indices, feature] == 1).ravel()]
    right_indices = indices[np.argwhere(X[node_indices, feature] == 0).ravel()]        
    return left_indices.tolist(), right_indices.tolist()
```

Does anyone have a simpler implementation? But that is still optimized and vectorized.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @user7138814 I've managed to optimize it as follows:

```
def split_dataset(X, node_indices, feature):
    indices = np.array(node_indices)
    mask = X[indices, feature] == 1
    left_indices = indices[mask]
    right_indices = indices[~mask]  
    return left_indices.tolist(), right_indices.tolist()
```

Comment: In this case converting the Boolean array to indices (with `argwhere`) is a bit redundant. You can use the Boolean array for indexing directly like so: `mask = X[indices, feature] == 1; left, right = indices[mask], indices[~mask]`

Comment: Thanks @user7138814, I've updated the solution with your hint, seems more clean indeed. I really appreciated your suggestion.